# Call of Duty: Modern Warfare Remastered out of memory 27 error

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I tried all solutions for this game by searching over google but no positive outcome. When I start the game after few seconds I got an error: **out of memory 27**. Idk, what is the problem? Anybody can throw some light on it? Heap of thanks in advance. Though, the game works in safe mode.

- Windows 10
- 12GB RAM
- 2GB AMD Radeon
- 2.7GHz Corei5-7200U

Answer (score 1):

So I checked the activision forum and [the following was recommended](https://community.activision.com/t5/Call-of-Duty-Infinite-Warfare/out-of-memory-27/td-p/10218831).

> Try verifying the cache more information available here.

This links to the following page: https://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Deleting-Old-Files-from-PlayStation-4-and-Xbox-One-Consoles/?q=cache

A second option that was mentioned on [the steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/393100/discussions/0/282992646970670697/)

> 1. BOOT PC INTO SAFE MODE VIA MSCONFIG
> 2. GO ON STEAM AND LAUNCH COD MWR CAMPAIGN AND MULTIPLAYER
> 3. RESTART PC INTO NORMAL MODE VIA MSCONFIG
> 4. LAUNCH MWR
> 5. ENJOY!

A replay of as user said this could be done easier.

> Nah that's the stupid way, all you need is a new config file. Put this folder in your game directory and the game will launch. https://www.sendspace.com/file/0q54vs

Try any of these, if they don't work let me know.

Comment: These solutions i have already tried. I found the patch over Youtube and that fixed my problem. Well, heap of thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Warda can you link the youtube video. Incase anyone has the same issue and finds this page.

Comment: [COD: Modern Warfare Remastered link of Patch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txxK7A1u-CM)